# Bootstrap tooltip and popover together on the same element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I am trying to apply bootstrap popover and tooltip on the same element(glyphicon-plus) .It is not working.

```
<a href ="#"><span class = "pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus" tooltip-title = "Save a bookmark" popover-title = "Save your bookmarks here" popover-content = "abc"></span></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).popover({ 

    content : $(this).attr("popover-content"),

    title : $(this).attr("popover-title")         
  })   

  $(this).tooltip({  

    placement : 'bottom', 

    title : $(this).attr("tooltip-title")         
  });     
});
```

Can someone guide what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You might start by actually initializing the popover JavaScript per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers ... or defining `$(this)` which, based on your code, is never established.

Comment: @RobertC Ok Thanks:) But then popover and tooltip both need to be initialised,right?

Answer (score 1):

Given that we have two separate HTML elements `<a>` and `<span>` why not place the `tooltip` in one and the `popover` trigger in the other?  Of course, you'll also need to initialize both:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips

The two JavaScript components you're using here are opt-in and your above code is missing any initialization that would allow them to ever load.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ 
    container: 'body', 
    html: false 
  });
  
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
    container: 'body', 
    html: false  
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save a Bookmark" data-placement="right">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Save your bookmarks here" data-content="abc"></span>
</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You should also specify the `container` for proper positioning and alignment, and whether you want to allow HTML in either (I've set it to false in my example).

Note also that this solution allows you to use `data-placement` for positioning so you don't need to limit yourself to ALL Tooltips or Popovers utilizing the same placement.  And since we've separated the triggers into different elements you don't need to worry about creating custom data-attributes from which to pull things like your title or content.  You're just using the standard Bootstrap attributes.